# Java using VS building with Maven Failed to get sources of local jar files

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, jar, local

I have been having some issues with the addition of a local Jar file (genetic) to a Maven project (capacityplan) in VS Code, however so far no sucess, hoping for some pros advices.

I have:

1. Installed:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Users\..\genetic\target\genetic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" -DgroupId=com.moga -DartifactId=genetic -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar
```

2. Added to my pom in capacityplan

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.moga</groupId>
      <artifactId>genetic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

3. Compiled capacityplan maven project

```
mvn install
```

4. Tried to execute

```
java -cp target/capacityplan-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.moga.planning.nsga2.RunCapacityPlanning
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.moga.planning.nsga2.RunCapacityPlanning
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/moga/population/PopulationVariable
```

PopulationVariable is a class from my jar genetic.
5. I am using VS Code so i went to Java Projects-> Maven Dependencies-> genetic and I discovered that the source was not there, all methods are empty or returning null.

```
 // Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler.
 // Implementation of methods is unavailable.
package com.moga.population;
public abstract class PopulationVariable<T> {
...
}
```

6. Tried to track down similar problems and found some similar issues, but none solved my problem.
   https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1231
   https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/689#issuecomment-434046529
7. Configurations

Java

java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)

POM

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>15</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
```

Given the context, do anyone have a clue of what could I try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the jar if convenient for me to reproduce your question?